# How to Return XML Node Ordinal, or delete node based on element value?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, xml, xquery

I have an XML document similar to this:

```
<Root>
  <Sub>
    <Record>
      <Guid>aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd</Guid>
    </Record>
    <Record>
       <Guid>opqiwuerl;kasdlfkjawop</Guid>
    </Record>
  </Sub>
</Root>
```

I am replacing an entire `<Record>` node based on some criteria.  The `<Record>` nodes contain a `<Guid>` that I can use to identify them (pretend those are valid GUIDs please!).

Knowing the GUID, I am returning that node's XML into a variable for further processing.  Downstream, I need to be able to delete that particular node so I that I can `insert` the modified version of the node back into the original document.

**Is there a way to determine the ordinal, or another way to use a `delete`/`replace` method  to remove a node based on an element's value?**

Comment: About getting the ordinal value from the XML you can have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12063361/569436) and a blog post by Adam Machanic. [Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/how-to-return-xml-node-ordinal-or-delete-node-based-on-element-value/40056#40056)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the value in a variable you can use [sql:variable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx) in the predicate for the delete.

```
declare @XML xml = '
<Root>
  <Sub>
    <Record>
      <Guid>aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd</Guid>
    </Record>
    <Record>
       <Guid>opqiwuerl;kasdlfkjawop</Guid>
    </Record>
  </Sub>
</Root>'

declare @Guid varchar(30) = 'aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd'

set @XML.modify('delete /Root/Sub/Record[Guid = sql:variable("@Guid")]')
```

Replacing a record with a new record would look something like this.

```
declare @XML xml = '
<Root>
  <Sub>
    <Record>
      <Guid>aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd</Guid>
      <Value>some value</Value>
    </Record>
    <Record>
       <Guid>opqiwuerl;kasdlfkjawop</Guid>
    </Record>
  </Sub>
</Root>'

declare @Guid varchar(30) = 'aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd'
declare @NewRecord xml = '
<Record>
  <Guid>aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd</Guid>
  <Value>some new value</Value>
</Record>'

set @XML.modify('insert sql:variable("@NewRecord") after (/Root/Sub/Record[Guid = sql:variable("@Guid")])[1]')
set @XML.modify('delete (/Root/Sub/Record[Guid = sql:variable("@Guid")])[1]')
```

First add the new record after the existing one and the delete the first occurrence where Guid is a match. Without `[1]` in the delete you will delete all occurrences, not only the first one.

Comment: I was hoping you would get the XML batsignal I sent up!  Thanks, I'll upvote now and accept once I confirm it!